# Mapping raw sql query into DTO object Spring

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, hibernate, jdbc

SPRING BOOT , JAVA 11 , POSTGRES

I have a big SQL query:

```
select c.id,c.image_url,c.status,c.name, cat.id,cat.name
from client_organization o join organization c
on o.organization_id = c.id
join client w on o.client_id = w.id
join org_category cat on c.category_id = cat.id
where w.id = ?
```

So i need to convert the given result to List of Data Transfer Objects(DTO).
If it is important, here is my DTO(constructor, getters and setters are not included):

```
public class OrganizationListDto {
    Long id;
    String image;
    Boolean status;
    String name;
    Long categoryId;
    String categoryName;
}
```

I have been looking for solution for some days and found that this operation can be implemented in different ways(jdbc, hibernate etc)
So please explain me what and when I need to use them?
How to implement this operation?

Answer (score 1):

```
Follow the below approach have used spingJpa
```

@Service
    public class OrganizationServiceImpl

```
{
    @Autowired
    OrganizationListRepository organizationListRepository;

        public OrganizationListDto  fetch(usrId)
        {
        OrganizationListDto orgListData = new OrganizationListDto();
    List<OrganizationListMapping> orgData = organizationListRepository.fetchData(usrId);
    BeanUtils.copy(orgData,orgListData)

        return orgData;
        }

}
```

@Repository
    public interface OrganizationListRepository extends JpaRepository{

```
@Query(native="true",value="select  cat.id as id,cat.name as name
from client_organization o join organization c
on o.organization_id = c.id
join client w on o.client_id = w.id
join org_category cat on c.category_id = cat.id
where w.id = usrId"
OrganizationListMapping fetchData(@Param ("usrId") Integer usrId);
}

public interface OrganizationListMapping {
    public Long getId();
    public String getName();

}


public class OrganizationListDto {
    Long id;
    String name;

}
```

Comment: The problem is ,that OrganizationListDTO is not @Entity.

Comment: yeah its DTO only Since interface OrganizationListMapping is used results from query are saved in those variables ...from that variables it is being copied into DTO'syou require entity only  to extends JPARepository in OrganizationListRepository interface